Question about Vector Field Geometry
I am confused about vector fields. Let $f_i:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ be real-valued functions for $i=1,2,3$.
Let $\vec{f}=(f_1,f_2,f_3):\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\vec{g}=(f_2,f_1,f_3):\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be two vector fields.
At first glance I thought $\vec{f}$ and $\vec{g}$ are almost the same objects geometrically because we get $\vec{g}$ if we just swap $f_1$ and $f_2$ of $\vec{f}$.
But for example, the vector field $(f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z))=(x,0,0)$ is completely different from the vector field $(f_2(x,y,z),f_1(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z))=(0,x,0)$.

I wonder why $\vec{f}$ and $\vec{g}$ are completely different geometrical objects.
Please explain this.
I know the following:
Let $f'_1(x,y,z)=f_1(y,x,z)$.
Let $f'_2(x,y,z)=f_2(y,x,z)$.
Let $f'_3(x,y,z)=f_3(y,x,z)$.
Let $\vec{h}=(f'_1,f'_2,f'_3)$.
Then, the vector field $\vec{f}$ and $\vec{h}$ are almost the same objects geometrically.

You can think of f and g as being reflections of one another in the x-y plane, but equal in z. Can you clarify further what you need explained so the question can be answered more clearly?

To obtain the second plot from the first, just rotate each arrow 90 degrees counterclockwise.

Also, those are linear fields. Do you understand the geometric difference between their matrices? One is nil-potent whereas the other is not. Their trace is also different and thus they represent different linear transformations. For each point, you are just drawing the resulting vector with base on that point. The trace of the matrix corresponds to the divergence of the field.

Swapping the x and y components has they effect of reflecting about the line $y=x$.  In practice this ends up being a 90 degree counter clock wise rotation .

@MathTrain Thank you very much for your comment.

@Keplerto Thank you very much for your answer.

@TurlocTheRed Thank you very much for your answer.
